# Excel data validation using conditional check

Tags: excel, validation, conditional-statements

I am trying to add validation to the following scenario...

A date keyed into cell A5 must be greater than the date in cell B4
AND
It must be less than a date in cell B5 if it is present.

The following custom data validation does not work....

```
=AND(A5>B4,IF(ISBLANK(B5),TRUE,A5<B5))
```

Although I'll be able to validate this via VBA, I would like to try and avoid that if possible.

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with Data Validation rules, but I must admit is not the most elegant way.

[image]

My Excel is not in english, so I'll try to translate.

I chose:

1. Allow Dates
2. **IMPORTANT**: Uncheck ignore blanks
3. Data Between
4. Inicial date = `B4+1` (+1 because it must be *greater* than)
5. End date = `=(IF(B5="";73050;B5-1))`

Yes, we must use a formula as `End Date` that will return 73050 if B5 is blank. 73050 equals to date 31 December 2099 (a huge range as you can see). You can adapt this to your needs. That's why I say it's not the most elegant way.

Not let's test it. My date in B4 is 01 March 2019. B5 is empty, so date in A5 must be only **greater** than 01 March 2019.

[image]

It works properly. Let's see if we type a date *equal to or less than 01 March 2019 while b5 is empty*.

[image]

It works too. Error message appears, and you cannot save this value into cell.

Now if we put a date in B5, data validation rule only admit values between both dates, excluding initial date and end date. Let's see it:

[image]

Please, note in last image I tested with date 31 MArch 2019. It is not allowed because B5 is 21 MArch 2019. **But if B5 is empty**, yes, it will be allowed because it's greater than B4.

[image]

So the trick here can be resumed in 2 parts:

1. IF B5 is empty, data validation rules will only admit dates between b4 and 31/12/2099
2. If B5 is not empty, data validation rules will only admit dates between B4 and B5

This is the best i can get. Hope you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: That works a treat - exactly what I need.  Thanks very much for your explanantion - I appreciate it.   It should be quite straight forward to adapt it where neccessary.

Comment: Thanks @MarkyD . Please, if this answer worked for you, mark it as correct so the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

I have managed to get the validation working by reworking the test...and removing the "ignore blank" check box (thanks for the hint in the answer below).

```
=AND(A5>B4,IF(B5 <> "",A5<B5, TRUE))
```

I am assuming that as soon as ISBLANK returns false, the validation will fail.